# Firebase: Is the error handling in the firebase stripe function example enough?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe.js

Firebase provides samples on GitHub for writing cloud functions.
I have a question about the "createStripeCharge" function.
It is possible that the write to the database fails?
If this would be the case, this function charges a customer but no object would be saved to the database. Is this right?
This error handling cannot be enough or do I understand something wrong?

The following line in the code confuses me:

> return event.data.adminRef.set(response);

You found the code on GitHub:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js

Or here:

```
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onWrite((event) => {
  const val = event.data.val();
  // This onWrite will trigger whenever anything is written to the path, so
  // noop if the charge was deleted, errored out, or the Stripe API returned a result (id exists)
  if (val === null || val.id || val.error) return null;
  // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
  return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${event.params.userId}/customer_id`).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.val();
  }).then((customer) => {
    // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key, protecting against double charges
    const amount = val.amount;
    const idempotency_key = event.params.id;
    let charge = {amount, currency, customer};
    if (val.source !== null) charge.source = val.source;
    return stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key});
  }).then((response) => {
    // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
    return event.data.adminRef.set(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
    // still logging an exception with Stackdriver
    return event.data.adminRef.child('error').set(userFacingMessage(error));
  }).then(() => {
    return reportError(error, {user: event.params.userId});
  });
});
```

Comment: It is probably more effective if you ask that question as an issue in the repository.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Maybe i will do that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a database write can fail is if it violates a security rule or if the function times out and gets cleaned up before it finishes.  When using the admin SDK, security rules don't apply, so that can't be the cause.  I suppose it's possible for the write to time out, so if you are very concerned about that, you should increase the timeout of the function.  The chance of a timeout occurring is extremely low.  If that happens, you should be able to manually resolve the concern of an end user without wasting a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you.Thats answers my question. Is this also the case if I use firestore? Is there any pattern to catch this problem programmatically or is manuell the easiest way to handle that?

Comment: Firestore is the same.  There is no automated error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The `onWrite()`:

triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in the Realtime Database.

```
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onWrite((event) => {
```

Therefore if the write to the database in the above location fails then `onWrite()` will not trigger.

Also if you want it to trigger when adding data only then you can use `onCreate()`:

It triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. But this answers not my question. This line confuses me: "return event.data.adminRef.set(response);" Can this write fail? If this would be the case, the customer would be charged but no object would be saved to the database. Is this right?